# How to pull onChange value into input's value

Tags: javascript, jscolor

I've been using http://jscolor.com/ but I'm not getting one thing
How can i take out the value of the color and paste it to value area in the form

I tried to put the script there but didn't work. How can i get `+this.color` into value area ?

```
<input value="" onchange="document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].style.backgroundColor = '#'+this.color">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work.... are you including:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscolor/jscolor.js"></script>
<script>
    var bgColorPicker = new jscolor.color(document.getELementById('bgColorChanger'),{});
    document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].style.backgroundColor = '#' + bgColorPicker.color";
    document.getElementByID('bgColorChanger').value = bgColorPicker.color;
</script>
```

before running the scripts?

```
<input id="bgColorChanger" value="" />
```

Will fill in the input value for you.

Comment: No, i did after... It just not passing the onchange data to value

Comment: Try all these changes. First time look into JSColor but I like it!

Comment: `http://jsfiddle.net/x5Pmd/` Glad your like it ! But have a look here brother value is not coming still..

Comment: You're concern is that the <body> is not changing color?

Comment: no i'm not getting the value have a look at the fiddle there is no change value...color picker is working good

Comment: I'm still messing around with it, I'll post an updated fiddle when I get it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that value is not going to change no matter what. I've even thrown some jQuery in on top of it and that value is stubborn. I'll mess around with it some more tomorrow. Let me know if you come up with anything.